# Setting Uploaded file of OneupUploaderBundle to form entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm using `OneupUploaderBundle` to upload files.
It uploads file and I can create a doctrine entity from uploaded files.
But after upload how can I set this files to main entity of my form?
for example I have a `Post` entity and `OneupUploaderBundle` created some `File` entities.
Now I want to:

1. Associate `File` entities to `Post` entity's OneToMany field
2. Delete those `File` entities if user never submit the `Post` form (delete orphan `File` entities)

How can I achieve this?